# Question about explode with php and delimiter

Tags: php, explode

If i use explode and i can scan string with different deimiters, the problem it´s verificate if delimiter really exists, i try to explain at this point

**If i have this :**

$scan="test";

**And put this :**

$exp=explode(".",$scan);

**The result always if do this it´s the same :**

print $exp[0];

**Give me :**

test

My question it´s how i can, don´t show the result **test** if really no have delimiter inside string, this it´s myquestion, because in many cases i have string with no delimiter but use explode and like me don´t show nothing if delimiter don´t exists relly inside string, but i see the result show the same if in the string don´t use delimiter in the firt value [0].

**Best Regards**

Comment: Check out PHP [`strpos`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [`strstr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php).

Answer (score 1):

you can check the result of explode if the array count is more than 1 element:

```
$exp=explode(".",$scan);

if (count($exp) > 1) {
// do whatever you want
}
```